# Is the iOS CLCircularRegion class is suitable for developing GEO based attendance

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an app for both iOS and android using ionic framework and cordova for attendance module. I am using third party plugin [Cordova Background Geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt) to do geo based attendance. But the problem for me is with radius of the geofence. In iOS there are some restrictions on radius it should not be less than 100-150 Meters. Clients who are going to use my app are not running any big MNC companies, For them them entire office circle will not be more than 30-50 meters radius. If I give give 200 metres restriction to them it will cover more area and the companies residing beside that also will cover under the geofence. So if the employee is far away from the company about 200 meters also can mark the attendance which is a security issue. I want to configure the less radius according to the client requirement. For me radius of 50 meters is some what suitable. If anyone is already implemented the geofence for the attendance module please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: The reason  that 100m is suggested as the smallest size for geofence is that when monitoring regions in the background, iOS only checks location periodically; A small region means that the user may enter and exit the region without being detected.  There are also limits to location accuracy, particularly indoors or in areas where GPS reception is poor

Comment: So how to solve the problem. Mine is Geo based attendance app for me 200 meters is very big one and that too if the user enters into the fence which is away 200 meters from the office location also he can mark the attendance. This is some what critical for me.

Comment: Maybe an iBeacon could work for you

Comment: That again cost some amount to my clients to purchase the device. And that too I am developing the hybrid app using third party plugin Cordova Background Geolocation. To do this I have to write iOS native coding which consumes the time.

Comment: What do you suggest with the radius of 50 meters in iOS does it works fine or not? Otherwise I have to go for the bigger radius only. Then How the other people are implementing geo based attendance in iOS.

Comment: I can't find the documentation right now, but I believe it has been stated by Apple (at a WWDC talk from memory) that if you specify a region radius <100m, then 100m will be used.  You can test 50m and see what happens.  You also need to consider real-world issues such as poor GPS coverage.  iBeacons are only about $25 and will give you 3-10m of proximity.